# Insert some space before the ToC chapter entry

Tags: spacing, minitoc

I am using `\mtcaddchapter[xyz]` to include `xyz` in a ToC.  I wonder if there is a way to insert some space, such as a tab, before `xyz` in the ToC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I used the following and it works.

```
\setlength{\cftchapindent}{0.25in}
```